# Materialize css carousel with custom navigation not working with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have been working on [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) for a while and I have created carousel view with custom navigation arrows just like the bootstrap.I have used [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) to initialize the carousel and It works . But am having problem on navigating between the slides.On pressing the navigation arrows the slides should moves as per the [Docs](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) ,but for some reasons it is not working.Please enlighten me.

```
      <div id="main" class="container-fluid" >
          <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
          <div class="carousel-fixed-item  align-center" style="top:50%">
           <!-- <a class="btn waves-effect black white-text darken-text-5">button</a> -->
           <div class="left">
          <a href="prev" @click.prevent="prev" class="left "><i class="material-icons white-text waves-effect waves-light left medium" style="border-radius:50%">chevron_left</i></a>  
          </div>
          <div class="right">
              <a href="next" @click.prevent="next" class="right "><i style="border-radius:50%" class=" white-text material-icons  waves-effect waves-light right medium">chevron_right</i></a>  
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item red blue-text" href="#one!">
            <h2>First Panel</h2>
            <p class="blue-text">This is your first panel</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item amber blue-text" href="#two!">
            <h2>Second Panel</h2>
            <p class="blue-text">This is your second panel</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item green blue-text" href="#three!">
            <h2>Third Panel</h2>
            <p class="blue-text">This is your third panel</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
            <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
            <p class="blue-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

And here's the script that I have used for **Initialisation** and **Navigation** of Slides.

```
 let vue = new Vue({
  el:"#main",
  data:{
   message:'hello'
   },
   mounted()
   {

   $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({fullWidth: true});

   },
   methods:{
   next()
   {
   alert('next'); // (*)

   $('carousel').carousel('next');
   },
   prev()
   {
   alert('prev');  // (**)
   $('carousel').carousel('prev');
   }
   }
   });
```

To check the working , if have used these alert statements (*) , (**).And to my suprise it works successfully am alerted on pressing the arrow buttons but the navigation of slides is not working.Please help me resolve my problem.

Comment: Just a guess, but in one part of the js above, you have $('.carousel.carousel-slider'). In another, you have $('carousel'). Shouldn't this identifier or class name be the same in both instances?

Comment: where exactly  ?

Comment: yes , you are right! thanks @tjcertified

Comment: And `$('carousel')` should be `$('.carousel')` (note the dot to make it a class selector)

Comment: you are right , i made a silly blunder thanks for notifying @agrm